# Synchronize three processes to print letters in a certain order

Tags: c, synchronization, mutex

I have three processes that can print one letter, A, B and C.

I want the following output.

```
AB AC AB AC AB .....
```

I have three binary semaphores initialized to the following values:

```
print_a = 1
print_b = 0
print_c = 0
```

Process A:

```
while(1) {
    wait(print_a);

    sleep(2); //So it's possible to see the output properly
    printf(" A");
    fflush(stdout);

    signal(print_b); 
}
```

Process B:

```
while(1) {
    wait(print_b);

    printf("B");
    fflush(stdout);

    signal(print_a);
    wait(print_b);

    signal(print_c);
}
```

Process C:

```
while(1) {
    wait(print_c);

    printf("C");
    fflush(stdout);

    signal(print_a);
}
```

Signal and wait are implemented using the filesystem. Wait is a spinlock trying to remove a file until it's successful. Signal creates a file.

```
void wait(char * file){
    while(unlink(file) != 0);

}

void signal(char * file){
    if(open(file, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 00777) == -1) {
        printf("Failed to open %s\n", file);
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

For the most part I get the correct output I want. However, occasionally the output will be wrong.

This is an example of the output:

```
AB AC AB AC AB AC AB AC AB AC AB AC AB AB AC AC AB AC AB AB AC A >>ACB<< AB AC AC AB AB AC AB

AC ABC AC AB >>ABC<< AB AC AC A AB AC AB AB AC AC AB AB AC >>ABC<< AB AC AC AB AB AC AC AB AB AC
```

I can't seem to figure out what's causing B or C to be printed after B or C instead of A.

UPDATE:

If I change wait to this:

```
void wait(char * file){
    while(unlink(file) != 0) {
            usleep(1000 * 100);
    }
}
```

It seems to work fine. Still don't understand why though.

Comment: I guess the question is - what does `wait` do when there is no file? does it wait for a file to appear, then remove it? Or does it move right along. The latter behavior would cause the problem you are seeing. Can't tell without seeing your implementation of `wait`...

Comment: Added wait and signal in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `print_b`, it seems to me you need to wait for `a` before signaling `c`:

```
while(1) {
    wait(print_b);
    wait(after_a);
    printf("B");
    fflush(stdout);
    signal(print_a);
    wait(after_a);
    signal(print_c);
}
```

because `after_a` will be set when `a` has printed, and if `a` has not reacted to the new signal yet, there is no reason why `c` would not come before the next `a`…

By the way I don't see where you are adding the space?

Comment: See my updated post. Why isn't C or B sometimes waiting for after_a? If we take B as example. Even if C runs instead of A after signal(print_a); signal(print_c); shouldn't C be blocked in wait(after_a)?